# Must validate images present on the page

Tags: java, image, selenium, testing, automation

I have a specific URL example https://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=207&t=How_To_Read_A_PDF_File_From_A_URL_In_Java (images present in URL not in any folder locations)

Requirements of Image specifications to validate:

1. 5-inch width = 672
2. 7-inch width = 840

I have 27 available <img and have to check:

1. how many images are 5-inch width = 672
2. how many images are 7-inch width = 840
3. is there are any images with other dimensions

Could you please tell me how can I validate it using java selenium...
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package selenium;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Tifoso {
    
    // in my case %USERPROFILE%\eclipse-workspace\Selenium
    public static String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    
    // chromedriver.exe location
    public static String chromedriverPath = userDir + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";  
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    // standard chromedriver initialization
    public static WebDriver startChromeDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");        
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        
        // setting 30 seconds wait to load pages
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        String url = "https://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=207&t=How_To_Read_A_PDF_File_From_A_URL_In_Java";
        driver.get(url);
        
        // empty lists
        List<WebElement> fiveInchWidthImages = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        List<WebElement> sevenInchWidthImages = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        List<WebElement> otherInchWidthImages = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        
        // getting all images
        List<WebElement> allImages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
        for (WebElement image: allImages) {
            // getting image width
            int width = image.getRect().getWidth();
            if (width == 672) {
                fiveInchWidthImages.add(image);
            }
            else if (width == 820) {
                sevenInchWidthImages.add(image);
            }
            else {
                otherInchWidthImages.add(image);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Number of images with width 672 is " + fiveInchWidthImages.size());
        System.out.println("Number of images with width 820 is " + sevenInchWidthImages.size());
        System.out.println("Number of images with other width is " + otherInchWidthImages.size());
        
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port 4826
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Pro 17, 2020 8:25:10 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Number of images with width 672 is 0
Number of images with width 820 is 0
Number of images with other width is 27
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Please mark the answer as useful. Thanks.